# Program exits with exit code 1 and also time limit exceeded

Tags: c, primes

We need to write a code for generating prime numbers in a given range.

**Errors**

1. I have optimized the code many times but still getting *time limit exceeded* on spoj.com.
2. My code exits with exit code 1

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    int num1, num2, i, j, flag, temp,two=2,test;

    scanf("%d",&test);
    for(int z=0;z<test;z++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);
        if(num1<=2)
        {
            printf("%d\n",two);
        }
        temp = num1;
        if ( num1 % 2 == 0)
        {
            num1++;
        }
        for (i = num1; i <= num2; i = i + 2)
        {
            flag = 0;
            for (j = 3; j <= i / 2; j+=2)
            {
                if ((i % j) == 0)
                {
                    flag = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (flag == 0&&i!=1)
            {
                printf("%d\n", i);   
            }
        }
    }      
}
```

I have also attached images for the showing the errors.

- [Shows time limit exceeded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fO6m6.png)
- [Shows exit code 1 error after input of 1 to 100000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvEpW.png)

Please help me optimizing the code or tell me what is wrong.

Comment: b) `int main(void) { /* ... */ return 0; }`

Comment: `for (j = 3; j <= i / 2; j += 2)` : the loop should end and the square root of `i`, not at `i/2`.

Comment: Thank You @pmg it works , silly of me